# How to develop C extensions for PHP apps?

Tags: php, php-extension

My PHP app has a number-crunching part that is just to slow for PHP, so I was thinking of building a custom C extension, but it is impossible to find any good reference to start with :(

Is there a guide on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best resource, although outdated in several aspects (it only covers PHP until version 5.1) is [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) by Sara Golemon. Even more outdated is the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/internals). On the other hand, the content on the [PHP wiki](http://wiki.php.net/) is very up-to-date, but also quite incomplete and not very oriented for beginners. See also [these articles](http://devzone.zend.com/public/view/tag/Extension), part V of [Advanced PHP Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325616) by George Schlossnagle, chapter 14 of [Programming PHP](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/index.htm) by Rasmus Lerdorf and Kevin Tatroe and, specially, [these slides](http://conf.phpquebec.com/slides/2009/PHP_Extension_Writing-phpquebec_2009.pdf).

Finally, the most authoritative source you'll find is the [source code](https://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/) of the extensions bundled with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer but more like a suggestion,  There are tools out there to compile your php to an executable, which you could just then use as an extension.  This Would uniform your code a bit and unify your project.  I have tried something like this a while ago.  The compiled php acts no differently than the compiled c would.

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP's embeded SAPI. Extending and Embedding PHP covers that. But he specifically says he has a web app with a portion he wants to optimize, so I guess that wouldn't be what he wants.

Comment: @Artefacto, thanks.  What your commented makes sense, but i would think compiled php would be alot faster than its interpreted version.

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be a command line tool written in C, that you start from PHP and communicate with over stdin/stdout. In many cases this is much easier to write and to deploy, but it ultimately depends on your use case.

Comment: This is also generally slower.