# Making C functions available to php

Tags: php, c, enums, php-extension, dll

I have a C dll containing functions and enumerations I want to make accessible from php.
How can I do it?

Comment: this may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970682

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an extension. You do need some C experience but [this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021) is pretty easy to follow.

**edit** I googled around out of curiosity, apparently you can sort-of dynamically load a dll from php using [w32api](http://it.php.net/manual/en/ref.w32api.php). I'd still go for the extension ;-)