# Start compiling PHP extensions

Tags: php, php-extension

I have code that is straight forward, but intensive. I would like to compile it into a PHP extension. What is the simplest / best practice for going about that?

I have a Java background, so writing the C / C++ code shouldn't be an issue. I would, however, like to avoid any pitfalls along the way.

A simple tutorial or walk through is something I haven't been able to find. Plenty of examples, but nothing aimed at someone new to doing this.

It looks like a more arduous road then I though, especially with all the lovely [C quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644634/does-making-the-iterator-a-pointer-speed-up-a-c-loop).

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) and this [Zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021) seem to cover quite a bit of ground in regards to writing PHP extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php-extension/info) for [`php-extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php-extension) and in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970682/how-to-develop-c-extentions-for-php-apps/2970709#2970709), also linked from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should try SWIG for generating wrapper for your source code, and then create your extension. It supports various languages like Java, C/C++ and makes it as simple as possible.